# Can I simplify this ajax call using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: "/Administration/Locations/DoAction",
    data: { partitionKey: id.substring(14),
            rowKey: id.substring(4, 14),
            action: ac,
            datastore: $("#DataSource").val()
    },
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function (data) {
      xx
    },
    error: function (x, t, m) {
      xx
    }
```

Can I can simplify this using jQuery to make the post? Note that id and ac are javascript variables assigned earlier.

Comment: Simplify in what way? This is pretty simple code as it is, but there might be something that can be changed in the context of your other code. Can you explain your question a little more?

Comment: What would you like to simplify there? Looks pretty raw/simple to me.

Comment: `async:false` defeats the purpose of ajax.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: but it is needed in some cases.

Comment: How much simpler do you want it? If you need async and traditional, not really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: When do you ever need async:false ?

Comment: This is a better question for http://s.tk/review

Comment: @Soren: For example if you need to use the result of the AJAX call in the upper function (function which holds the ajax call). Or you need to set some variables which are used in the the upper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.post("/Administration/Locations/DoAction",
    { partitionKey: id.substring(14),
            rowKey: id.substring(4, 14),
            action: ac,
            datastore: $("#DataSource").val()
    },
    function (data) {
      xx
    },
    "json"
).error(function() {
  xx
});
```

Documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

`$.post()` is same as

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Looks good. I'm just checking out that link to see how I can set async: false.  I need that in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I am making this call in a function. After I leave the function will the $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); still be in effect?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application you might be able to use a global errorhandler and/or successhandler. Most likely only the first however. Combine with answer from Peter, and you should be good to go. To set these global handlers use

```
$.ajaxError(...)
$.ajaxSuccess(...)
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/. There's a list down a ways on that page listing all the global ajaxHandler-initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
traditional: !0,
url: "/Administration/Locations/DoAction",
data: {
    partitionKey: id.substring(14),
    rowKey: id.substring(4, 14),
    action: ac,
    datastore: $("#DataSource")
        .val()
},
async: !1,
dataType: "json",
timeout: 1e3,
success: function () {},
error: function () {}
})
```